# container for quick name lookup

Tags: c++, containers, std

I want to store strings and issue each with a unique ID number (an index would be fine). I would only need one copy of each string and I require quick lookup. I check if the string exist in the table often enough that i notice a performance hit. Whats the best container to use for this and how do i lookup if the string exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest tr1::unordered_map.  It is implemented as a hashmap so it has an expected complexity of O(1) for lookups and a worst case of O(n).  There is also a boost implementation if your compiler doesn't support tr1.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    tr1::unordered_map<string, int> table;

    table["One"] = 1;
    table["Two"] = 2;

    cout << "find(\"One\") == " << boolalpha << (table.find("One") != table.end()) << endl; 
    cout << "find(\"Three\") == " << boolalpha << (table.find("Three") != table.end()) << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not use unordered_map in T1, it doesn't have the reserve method and if you insert a lot of string during the insertion phase you are going to have a lot of rehashing.

Comment: Also unordered_map for long strings is worst than a std::map

Answer (score 7):

try this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [adrinael.net](http://adrinael.net/containerchoice.png))</sub>

Answer (score 5):

Try std::map.

Answer (score 4):

**First and foremost** you must be able to **quantify** your options.  You have also told us that the main usage pattern you're interested in is **lookup**, not insertion.

*Let `N` be the number of strings that you expect to be having in the table, and let `C` be the average number of characters in any given string present in the said table (or in the strings that are checked against the table).*

1. In the case of a **hash-based approach**, for each lookup you pay the following costs:

   - `O(C)` - calculating the hash for the string you are about to look up
   - between `O(1 x C)` and `O(N x C)`, where `1..N` is the cost you expect from traversing the bucket based on hash key, here multiplied by `C` to re-check the characters in each string against the lookup key
   - total time: between `O(2 x C)` and `O((N + 1) x C)`
2. In the case of a **`std::map`-based approach** (which uses red-black trees), for each lookup you pay the following costs:

   - total time: between `O(1 x C)` and `O(log(N) x C)` - where `O(log(N))` is the maximal tree traversal cost, and `O(C)` is the time that `std::map`'s generic `less<>` implementation takes to recheck your lookup key during tree traversal

In the case of large values for `N` and in the absence of a hash function that guarantees less than log(N) collisions, or if you just want to play it safe, **you're better off using a tree-based (`std::map`) approach**.  If N is small, by all means, use a hash-based approach (while still making sure that hash collision is low.)

Before making any decision, though, you should also check:

- http://meshula.net/wordpress/?p=183
- http://wyw.dcweb.cn/mstring.htm

Answer (score 2):

sounds like an array would work just fine where the index is the index into the array. To check if it exists, just make sure the index is in bounds of the array and that its entry isn't NULL.

EDIT: if you sort the list, you could always use a binary search which should have fast lookup.

EDIT: Also, if you want to search for a string, you can always use a `std::map<std::string, int>` as well. This should have some decent lookup speeds.

Comment: wait so you want to be able to say exists("my_string")?

Comment: I thought that you wanted to be able to do: C[index] to get the string.

Answer (score 2):

Are the Strings to be searched available statically? You might want to look at a [perfect hashing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to use std::map.

It works like this:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

...

   map<string, int> myContainer;
   myContainer["foo"] = 5; // map string "foo" to id 5
   // Now check if "foo" has been added to the container:
   if (myContainer.find("foo") != myContainer.end())
   {
       // Yes!
       cout << "The ID of foo is " << myContainer["foo"];
   }
   // Let's get "foo" out of it
   myContainer.erase("foo")
```

Comment: As I commented on @Teran's answer: Wouldn't it be <int, std::string>? He wants to look up given the UID, not the string.

Comment: he said he wants to lookup by a string in the comment to terans answer if i got him right

Comment: well he didnt... but we guess he did :)

Answer (score 0):

[Google sparse hash](http://code.google.com/p/google-sparsehash/) maybe